# Android SQLite database removing a record

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am now building an android phone book app and employing the method of SQLite database to store records. In my database, there is _id column which is a primary key and will increase automatically. A strange thing is that when I delete records, the removed _id number is not re-used.

E.g. Originally the database is

```
_id name
1   Peter
2   Mary
```

After deleting 2 (Mary), when I add a new record (John), I found that John is placed with an id = 3.

So my question is: is Mary still there? Is it just flagged to be "deleted" but not really deleted? If so, would this be a wastage of memory and should I do something to remove it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row is deleted.  Generating the auto increment ID is implementation specific. It is upto to the autoincrement algorithm to assign the new id or reuse the deleted ID. Please refer sqlite tutorial : http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

This is a quote in the mentioned in above link:
With AUTOINCREMENT, rows with automatically selected ROWIDs are guaranteed to have ROWIDs that have never been used before by the same table in the same database. And the automatically generated ROWIDs are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing.
Note that "monotonically increasing" does not imply that the ROWID always increases by exactly one. One is the usual increment. However, if an insert fails due to (for example) a uniqueness constraint, the ROWID of the failed insertion attempt might not be reused on subsequent inserts, resulting in gaps in the ROWID sequence. AUTOINCREMENT guarantees that automatically chosen ROWIDs will be increasing but not that they will be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

No, after deleting row id 2, the record is completely deleted. The incrementing counter will continue from where it left off, so it is correct to see John with an id of 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your ID column an INT primary key and add auto increment to it.

Comment: I have done so, my code when creating the database is `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE phonebook (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, tel TEXT, email TEXT);");`

Comment: According to the documentation The ID column should the the alias for the rowid IF you have done what you stated in the comment above. http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Do things add up if you SELECT rowid, * FROM phonebook ?

Comment: I can still see John to have an id of 3. Actually my main concern is just that whether the records are really deleted, so as long as records are really deleted, the id does not really matter... Anyway thanks for your answer!